# Node req.body undefined on xhttp delete request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, pg-promise

I have a fairly extensive Node.js back-end with Express and pg-promise. Most of it is working perfectly as I expected it to.

Currently I am trying to create a function that deletes from multiple tables if I pass in a value for it to do so. My problem is that when I try to use req.body.cont (cont is a variable to continue) I get undefine

I have tried changing the names of the variables, trying to mimic how I sent data to the server before.

```
function removeUser(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.cont);
  if (req.body.cont) {
    console.log('hello');
    deleteLocCustId(req, res, next, req.params.id);
  }
  db.result('delete from customer where id = $1', req.params.id)
    .then(function(result) {
      if (!req.body.cont) {
        res.status(200).json({
          status: 'success',
          message: `Removed ${result.rowCount} customer`
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

When I use this same method to create a customer it works perfectly.

```
function createCustomer(req, res, next) {
  const newCustomer = new PQ(
    'insert into customer(customer_name, ID, parent, symID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)'
  );
  newCustomer.values = [
    req.body.customerName,
    req.body.cId,
    req.body.parentName,
    req.body.symPID
  ];
  db.none(newCustomer)
    .then(() => {
      if (req.body.locationObject) {
        return createLocation(req, res, next);
      }
      return null;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

When I try to console.log(req.body.cont); I get undefined from my server.

Comment: Please post the full error, are you getting undefined, or getting cannot read property cont of undefined or other

Comment: I do not get an error at all. When I try to access req.body.cont to call the deleteLocCustId even if I pass in the correct cont it will not enter. When I console.log req.body.cont all I get is undefined

Comment: Using correct body parser for the content type of the request? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is actually sent. We have no way to know from what is shown why it is undefined without more debugging details

Comment: I had to set the header which I forgot to do. That fixed my issue. thanks!